# Visualize Thousands of nodes on Neo4J (on Screen / Zoom Out limit)

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph with 2000+ Nodes. 
Using Neo4J Browser, I can display them "outside of the screen" and drag the viewport to navigate through the Graph, but I do not seem to be able to Zoom Out enough to display my whole graph on the same screen. 
Reaching a certain point, the zoom out icon grays out, and one cannot get any further. 
I read the Developer Manual / Reference but I did not come across sufficient information regarding this.
Any help/information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

imho, the neo4j browser is an admin console. For custom viz needs, you should build a custom viz (lots of existing js libs)

The number of displayed nodes is limited to 300 by default in the browser. Might help to increase it (see the Gear tab then Graph Visualization/Initial Node Display)

Comment: Yeah I expanded the Initial Node Display prop to 2000 and I ended up using APOC export and Graph Stream plugin on Gephi, but that's quite cumbersoem tbh